# Bug with re.finditer() function and re.DOTALL flag in re module of Python 3.6?

Tags: python, regex, pattern-matching, newline, flags

I'm getting weird results when I use the re.DOTALL in re.finditer() when using Python 3.6.
I don't know if this is the expected operation or If I'm missing something or if its a bug.

**CASE 1**

I try this version of a string with an embedded newline.

I expect to get 2 matched values back: m1 = 'abc' and m2 = ' de'

```
import re
result = re.finditer('.*', 'abc\n de', flags=0)
m1 = result.__next__()
#    <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 3), match='abc'>
m2 = result.__next__()
#    <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(3, 3), match=''>
m3 = result.__next__()
#    <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(4, 7), match=' de'>
m4 = result.__next__()
#    <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(7, 7), match=''>
```

Whats with the match values m2 and m4?

**CASE 2**

I try this with re.DOTALL, and I expect to get back one match, m1 = 'abc\n de'

```
result = re.finditer('.*', 'abc\n de', flags=re.DOTALL)
m1 = result.__next__()
#     <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 7), match='abc\n de'>
m2 = result.__next__()
#     <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(7, 7), match=''>
```

Whats with the extra matches? How do I make the results work as expected?

I want the first case to return ...

```
m1 = 'abc'
m2 = ' de'
```

... and the second case to return

```
m1 = 'abc\n de'
```

*and nothing else.*

Comment: If you don't want to match empty strings, use `.+` instead of `.*`.

Answer (score 1):

Your pattern is

```
.*
```

This means "match zero or more characters"; zero-width matches are permitted.

In your first case, the `m2` and `m4`s exist because the pattern stops matching at the newline, then tries to find a new match starting at that position (index 3). No characters are matched, but the pattern still permits it, because it's `.*`, hence the first match has

```
span=(0, 3)
```

and the second match has

```
span=(3, 3)
```

The same thing is happening for `span=(7, 7)` in `m4` and in your `DOTALL` code.

It sounds like you want a match only if there's *at least one character* - repeat with `+` rather than `*`:

```
re.finditer('.+', 'abc\n de')
```